# How to select particular edges with a python script?

Tags: python, scripting

How to select all the edges through the YZ plane with a python script ?

[image]

---

**update**

I know this script which do it for faces but I don't know the equivalent for edges :

```
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

for face in bm.faces:

    center = face.calc_center_median()

    if center.x == 0:

        face.select_set(True)

bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

Comment: Not sure why the question got a downvote, but I suspect because it is more like a request for script without any signs of an attempt by you to research how such a script might be put together.

Comment: how would you decide the x component of the plane? Remember scripts don't have eyes, like ours that let us immediately say ' oh of course, that vertex and edge lies on the plane '. Would your script need to find this plane autonomously or would you be giving it a helping hand by providing a pre-selection first

Comment: the x component of the plan is zero, it's at the origin.

Comment: just select the verts instead and automatically the edges are selected

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Armed with the extra information consider:

```
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

EPSILON = 1.0e-5

for vert in bm.verts:
    if -EPSILON <= vert.co.x <= EPSILON:
        vert.select = True

bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

Some clarification perhaps:

EPSILON represents a value that is close to 0. If you've ever inspected coordinates closely in Blender you will find a cut off point maybe at around 6 or 7 digits after the decimal where you start to encounter artefacts in the representation of that float. Because 0 and 0.0000012312423 are not the same number you can't simply do a check for equality with 0, instead you might check is the x component within EPSILON tolerance.

Here I make the significant digit 5 places after the decimal point, from practical experience i've found this to be sufficient.

```
>>> 1.0e-5 == 0.00001
True
```

The above will select just the vertices, from that point selecting the edges shouldn't be too difficult. Here's a quick implementation

```
import bpy, bmesh

me = bpy.context.object.data

bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

EPSILON = 1.0e-5
for vert in bm.verts:
    if -EPSILON <= vert.co.x <= EPSILON:
        vert.select = True

for edge in bm.edges:
    if edge.verts[0].select and edge.verts[1].select:
        edge.select = True

bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```

[image]

Comment: As always - very nice zeffi :)

Comment: @poor thanks! I always answer these questions with at least a working solution, in the hope that someone who knows more will get agitated and offer an alternative. The more answers the merrier.

Comment: I've only thought about if there is a build-in epsilon value, remembered vaguely there was one in c++, but can't find it at the moment.

Comment: How come 
import bmesh as bm
bm.edges 
will output bmesh has no attribute edges

Comment: @JuneWang  because if you `import bmesh as bm` , then `bm` is just an alias for the `bmesh` module, and you are doing something like `bm = bm.new()`? look at the examples at https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/bmesh.html?highlight=bmesh#module-bmesh