# Learning Scripting with Python and Blender Edge or vertices question

Tags: python, scripting, vertices

I'm learning to write script in Blender (along my path of coding education and practical usage) and I'm to a point where i'm wanting to adjust certain vertices and certain edges. Can I create vertex groups or give specific edges variable names so I can adjust minor measurements later down the road?

Comment: Hi. Regarding creating Vertex Groups there is this in the Blender Python API: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.object.html#bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_add An Internet search for blender python select specific vertices gave, among other results, this old answered question here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43127/how-do-i-select-specific-vertices-in-blender-using-python-script Regarding specific edges, there is this old answered question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27698/how-to-select-particular-edges-with-a-python-script Continued...

Comment: Keep in mind that the Python code that Blender uses has changed since these questions were asked and there is a good chance that the code in the answers will need to be modified.